# Where can i find LeClair's 2007/8 papers on the Riemann Hypothesis?

Tags: reference-request, riemann-hypothesis

I'm reading Schumayer's excellent expository article, ''Physics of the Riemann Hypothesis'', and on pp. 21-22 in the article, Schumayer refers to certain two papers of LeClair, published in 2007 and 2008.

However, on the references list, the paper wasn't cited by its title, which makes it difficult to search if one hadn't seen it before.

Therefore, i'm kindly asking if anyone knows where i can find these papers ?

Comment: Try searching on Arxiv by name of author. His given name is André. He's also a member of this site, maybe you can find some information in his profile.

Comment: I went and looked for Schumayer's article too (co-author Hutchinson).  It's at https://arxiv.org/abs/1101.3116 if anyone else was wondering.

Answer (score 6):

Here is one of them, from the arxiv, *Quantum statistical mechanics of gases in terms of dynamical filling fractions and scattering amplitudes*: https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0611187

Here is the other one: *Interacting Bose and Fermi gases in low dimensions and the Riemann hypothesis* https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0611043

Comment: I checked Schumayer's citations against MathSciNet to find the titles, then searched the arxiv.